# Is there a benefit to harvesting my garden?

Tags: cookie-clicker

I've unlocked the garden in cookie clicker. There is a counter for the number of (mature) plants harvested. Other than Bakeberry, why would I harvest plants?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As stated in [this wikia article](http://cookieclicker.wikia.com/wiki/Garden):

> In the Garden, plants and fungi can be grown and crossbred, obtaining
>   new species as a result. Crops provide various benefits depending on
>   the species, some granting passive buffs as they sit planted in the
>   Garden, while others give rewards when harvested.

There is also another document with much more information concerning Garden and what it is used for, [here](https://docs.google.com/document/u/1/d/e/2PACX-1vR-EfFZl71Y3q4-EPrXB9dZDu_3n6ZsT0KGxUPYfVJae8mj6OK2ame93TZUp8pfhjMsmE5PlZS6DxRq/pub). Author claims to have read this information direclty in the source code. You will find there:

- Recipes for plant mutations
- Plant mutation mechanics
- Efficient plant arrangements for breeding
- Soil Type Data
- Plant Effects
- Garden Tools
- Garden Related Achievements
- Garden related upgrades

Additional information related to plants can be found on [this link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QToJWQnpJGglD4JxH6pThtWtqjSUBDpAAo5BJvbdET8/htmlview?sle=true#gid=2090827045).

Reading your question again, I will describe Plant Effects, as it is I think the correct answer to your question.

### Plant Effects

- Baker's Wheat: +1% CpS
- Thumbcorn: +2% cookikes per click
- Cronerice: +3% grandma CpS
- Gildmillet: +1% golden cookie gains, +0.1% golden cookie effect duration
- Clover: +1% golden cookie frequency
- Golden Clover: +3% golden cookie frequency
- Shimmerlily: +1% golden cookie frequency, +1% golden cookie gains, +1% item drops
- Elderwort: +1% wrath cookie gains, +1% wrath cookie gains, +1% grandma CpS, Immortal (immune to contamination and decay), surrounding plants (3x3) age 3% faster
- Bakeberry: +1% CpS, Harvest when mature for +30 minutes of CpS (capped at 3% of bank)
- Chocoroot: +1% CpS, Harvest when mature for +3 minutes of CpS (capped at 3% of bank) predictable growth
- White Chocoroot:
  +1% golden cookie gains, Harvest when mature for +3 minutes of CpS (caped at 3% of bank) predictable growth
- White Mildew: +1% CpS, may spread as brown mold
- Brown Mold: -1% CpS, may spread as white mildew
- Meddleweed: useless, may overtake nearby plants, Sometimes drops Brown Mold or Crumbspore when uprooted
- Whiskerbloom:
  +0.2% milk effects
- Chimerose: +1% reindeer gains, +1% reindeer frequency
- Nursetulip: Surrounding plants (3x3) are 20% more efficient, -2% cps
- Drowsyfern: +3% CpS, -5% cookies per click, -10% golden cookie frequency
- Wardlichen: 2% less wrath cookies, wrinklers spawn 15% slower
- Keenmoss: +3% item drops
- Queenbeet: +0.3% golden cookie effect duration, -2% CpS, harvest when mature for +1 hour of CpS (max. 6% of bank)
- Juicy Queenbeet: -10% CpS, surrounding plants (3x3) are 20% less efficient, harvest when mature for a sugar lump
- Duketater: harvest when mature for +2 hours of CpS (max. 8% of bank)
- Crumbspore: explodes into up to 1 minute of CpS at the end of its life cycle (max. 1% of bank), may overtake nearby plants (contamination)
- Doughshroom: explodes into up to 5 minutes of CpS at the end of its life cycle (max. 3% of bank), may overtake nearby plants
- Glovemorel: +4% cookies per click, +1% cursor CpS, -1% CpS
- Cheapcap: buildings and upgrades are 0.2% cheaper
- Fool’s bolete: +2% golden cookie frequency, -5% golden cookie gains, -2% golden cookie duration, -2% golden cookie effect duration
- Wrinklegill: wrinklers spawn 2% faster, wrinklers eat 1% more
- Green rot: +0.5% golden cookie duration, +1% golden cookie frequency, +1% item drops
- Shriekbulb: -2% CpS, surrounding plants (3x3) are 5% less efficient
- Tidygrass: surrounding tiles (5x5) develop no weeds or fungus
- Everdaisy: surrounding tiles (3x3) develop no weeds or fungus, immortal
- Ichorpuff: surrounding plants (3x3) ages half as fast, surrounding plants (3x3) are half as efficient